# subreport causes multiple output of master report lines

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a master report which prints a line at a time and a sub report which can print x number of lines for each line of the master report (both in detail band).

The number of lines in the sub report seems to cause that the master report output gets repeated for every record on the sub report. 
The sub report gets a parameter from the master report which is used in the sub report query.

The first line of the master report is repeated 4 times because the sub report contains 4 lines. 
When sub report contains 2 lines, master report output is repeated twice.
How can I avoid this? Any suggestions, please. 
My first try at master and sub reports.

Example of report output:

```html
SAP B1 Snr Support Cons : Carin Botha Hrs 7.75 600.00 4650.00 
 1.50 Changes on QlikView Models
0.75 Trysome DB in Recovery Mode
2.50 QlikView Services Model Changes
3.00 QlikView Workshop:Riaan Venter
SAP B1 Snr Support Cons : Carin Botha Hrs 7.75 600.00 4650.00 
1.50 Changes on QlikView Models
0.75 Trysome DB in Recovery Mode
2.50 QlikView Services Model Changes
3.00 QlikView Workshop:Riaan Venter
SAP B1 Snr Support Cons : Carin Botha Hrs 7.75 600.00 4650.00
 1.50 Changes on QlikView Models
0.75 Trysome DB in Recovery Mode
2.50 QlikView Services Model Changes
3.00 QlikView Workshop:Riaan Venter
SAP B1 Snr Support Cons : Carin Botha Hrs 7.75 600.00 4650.00
 1.50 Changes on QlikView Models
0.75 Trysome DB in Recovery Mode
2.50 QlikView Services Model Changes
3.00 QlikView Workshop:Riaan Venter
SAP B1 Snr Support Cons : Carin Botha Hrs 1.00 600.00 600.00
1.00 Database Recovery error
SAP B1 Snr Support Cons : Carin Botha Hrs 4.00 600.00 2400.00
1.50 MOZ: License server cannot connect
2.50 Moz and Zam Posting Periods
SAP B1 Snr Support Cons : Carin Botha Hrs 4.00 600.00 2400.00
1.50 MOZ: License server cannot connect
2.50 Moz and Zam Posting Periods
```

Comment: Can you post an image of your master report?  And from the view above, can you confirm there is only 3 records in the dataset of your master report?

Comment: @trubs, the records from the maser report are the ones starting with:        SAP B1 Snr Support Cons : Carin Botha Hrs 7.75 600.00 4650.00            and the records generated by the sub report are the ones starting with the numeric values, in other words, the Hrs 7.75 (in master report line) is made up of the 1.5, 0.75, 2.5 and 3.0 hrs underneath it which comes from the sub report. The master report prints one line and the sub report adds 1 or more lines directly underneath the master report line. Yes, only 3 records in the dataset of my master report.

Comment: Problem solved. Read sub report table in master report as well, although i did not display it in master report. Took join to table and two fields out of master report  and it worked 100%.